# Kafka-connect without schema registry

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, parquet, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a kafka-topic and I would like to feed it with AVRO data (currently in JSON). I know the "proper" way to do it is to use schema-registry but for testing purposes I would like to make it work without it.

So I am sending AVRO data as `Array[Byte]` as opposed to regular Json objects:

```
    val writer = new SpecificDatumWriter[GenericData.Record]("mySchema.avsc")
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val encoder = EncoderFactory.get.binaryEncoder(out, null)
    writer.write(myAvroData, encoder)
    encoder.flush
    out.close
    out.toByteArray
```

The schema is embarked within each data; how can I make it work with kafka-connect? The kafka-connect configuration currently exhibits the following properties (data is written to s3 as json.gz files), and I want to write Parquet files:

```
{
  "name": "someName",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "120",
  "topics": "user_sync",
  "s3.region": "someRegion",
  "s3.bucket.name": "someBucket",
  "s3.part.size": "5242880",
  "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
  "filename.offset.zero.pad.width": "20",
  "flush.size": "5000",
  "rotate.interval.ms": "600000",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd/HH",
  "timezone" : "UTC",
  "locale": "en",
  "partition.duration.ms": "600000",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field" : "ts",
  "schema.compatibility": "NONE"
```

I suppose I need to change `"format.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat`? But is it enough?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonConverter` will be unable to consume Avro encoded data since the binary format contains a schema ID from the registry that's needed to be extracted before the converter can determine what the data looks like

You'll want to use the [registryless-avro-converter](https://github.com/farmdawgnation/registryless-avro-converter), which will create a Structured object, and then should be able to converted to a Parquet record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is this the only way? The schema is already embedded in the data.

Comment: Yes, this converter assumes the "writer schema" is in the data, but Avro still requires a "reader schema" to deserialize

Comment: Thanks a lot! And if I use your library, the only thing I have to do is switch "value.converter" from "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" to "me.frmr.kafka.connect.RegistrylessAvroConverter" ? As you can see, I have no key.converter field. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Change that and add the property that points to the schema file on your connect worker file path. The key converter defaults to the one in the worker properties if you didn't specify it for the connector